# PHPExcel - How to export results from multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Is there a way to export results from multiple queries to single excel sheet using PHPExcel? Here's what I have so far and it works with one query:

```
<?php
// connection with the database
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "admin";
$dbpass = "password";
$dbname = "databasename";

mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// require the PHPExcel file
require 'classes/PHPExcel.php';

// simple query

$query = "SELECT denisCheckedby, denisStatus, denisDate, denisNotes FROM tblDenis ORDER by denisID DESC";
$headings = array('Checked By', 'Successfull?','Date','Notes');

if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
    // Create a new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Backup Check');

    $rowNumber = 1;
    $col = 'A';
    foreach($headings as $heading) {
       $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading);
       $col++;
    }

    // Loop through the result set
    $rowNumber = 2;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
       $col = 'A';
       foreach($row as $cell) {
          $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
          $col++;
       }
       $rowNumber++;
    }

    // Freeze pane so that the heading line will not scroll
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->freezePane('A2');

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);

    // Set column widths
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setAutoSize(true);

    // Set fonts
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:D1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

    // Save as an Excel BIFF (xls) file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');

   header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Backup Check.xls"');
   header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

   $objWriter->save('php://output');
   exit();
}
echo 'a problem has occurred... no data retrieved from the database';
?>
```

How do I do the same using multiple queries? For example, my 2nd query would be:

```
"SELECT curtisCheckedby, curtisStatus, curtisDate, curtisNotes FROM tblCurtis ORDER by curtisID DESC";
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't control how you run your database queries, it only provides methods for setting data values in cells within an worksheet... the onus is on your script to execute the queries and to specify the cells where you want data from each query stored

Comment: if you want multiple query results in the sheet, then you'll need multiple rounds of fetch/stuff-in-to-spreadsheet code. basically, don't ->save() until you're actually really done.